# Android socket wait issue

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-asynctask

Hello I have an app that connect to a remote server using sockets

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(Ip, portNum), 7000);
```

I have 2 methods send & receive

the scenario in send is

```
 PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
```

in method receive

```
  String msg = "";
    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


        while (in.ready()) {

            msg = msg + (char) in.read();

        }
        socket.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in AsyncTask of a different class I call

```
 send();
 String response=receive();
```

The above code is not sending or receiving without a wait period

i.e

```
    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

I know sleep is a bad approach 
what is the best scenario should I use?

Is it better to make an AsyncTask within send method and another one for receive method.

Here is where I use sleep and what data send & receive

```
 client.send(some sql statement representED as json format);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
// sql select result represented as json
        String RESULT = client.recive();
```

Comment: We cannot see where you have that Sleep statement. Or if you have two of them.

Comment: Further you should tell and show us what you send. And what you expect as response.

Comment: I edited the question to show when to call sleep and what data sent & received.

Comment: We cannot see what you send and you did not tell what you expect to receive although i asked for it. Further you did not tell what the server expects to receive and what it would send as response.

Comment: what is send is a Json format  and what I expect to receive is also a json format for example 

data sent 
{  
   "date":"15/12/2017",
   "sqlStment":  
      "select name,id from users"
 
}

server response 
{
"isSuccessful":"true" ,

"data":[{"name":"Ali"},
{"id":"1"}]

}

Answer (score 1):

Likely your server is not listening before you try to connect. Though this is unclear from the code you have posted. You'll need to show both server and client code there.

Comment: I didn't write server code plus  the server is wrote in Go Programming Language not java , but the connection from desktop client (c#) is working fine without wait.